# How to go through a nested for loop?

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to make my code go through a nested for loop, but the loop refuses to follow my original construct of thought.

My code is shown below.

```
def couple(men_choice, women_choice):

possible_engagements = []

# men's first choice
for man in range(len(men_choice)):
    for woman in men_choice:
        pair = (man, woman[0])
        possible_engagements.append(pair)
    return possible_engagements
```

I am trying to design the first step of gale shapley algorithm, where each men will get paired with the first choice of woman in each of their list.

For example, if I have

```
>>> men_choice = [[1, 2, 3, 0], [3, 1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 3, 0], [3, 2, 0, 1]]

possible_engagements = [(0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 2), (0, 3)] # current output

possible_engagements = [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 3)] # desired output
```

Men's first choice of women are being outputted as I planned, but the index of men are not in sequence.

What problems do I have with my loop?

Comment: fix your indentation.

Comment: I've heard people speak that way about their code before - frustrated that it won't do what you tell it to do.  The contrary is true - it will always do exactly what you tell it to do, you just have to learn to speak its language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a list comprehension:

```
def couple(men_choice, women_choice):
    return [(i, x[0]) for i, x in enumerate(men_choice)]
```

As a for-loop generator:

```
def couple(men_choice, women_choice):
    for i, x in enumerate(men_choice):
        yield (i, x[0])
```

As a for-loop + list.append:

```
def couple(men_choice, women_choice):
    engagements = []
    for i, x in enumerate(men_choice):
        engagements.append((i, x[0]))
    return engagements
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one for loop to go through the mens choices, and to make sure you have no duplicate matchings, you have to check if the woman is already paired with another man.

```
def couple(men_choice, women_choice):

possible_engagements = []

# men's first choice
    for man in range(len(men_choice)):
            i = 0
            pair = (man, men_choice[i])
            while ([x[1] for x in possible_engagements].count(men_choice[i]) > 0):         #Check if woman is already chosen
                pair = (man, men_choice[i])
                i=i+1
            possible_engagements.append(pair)
    return possible_engagements
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return keyword is located inside your outer loop. This means that man will only take the value 0, hence your current output. The code below achieves your desired output.

```
men_choice = [[1, 2, 3, 0], [3, 1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 3, 0], [3, 2, 0, 1]]
women_choice = []


def couple(men_choice, women_choice):
    possible_engagements = []
    for man in range(len(men_choice)):
        possible_engagements.append((man, men_choice[man][0]))
    return possible_engagements


possible_engagements = couple(men_choice, women_choice)
print(possible_engagements)
```